# What is the name of this connector that is above my kitchen cupboard?

Tags: identification, connector, socket, outlet

This is the connector in question:

[image]

[image]

EDIT frame removed:

[image]

Bonus question: Can an amateur turn it into a power outlet to power a Philips Hue strip?

Comment: Are you sure it is a "socket" and not some service opening? What's inside the hole?

Comment: I'm not at all sure about my thermonalogy. I tried sticking a hooked plastic tool inside to 'forcefully' open it, but it couldn't come off. Do I need a specialized tool to get the cap off, or would a heatgun sufice?

Comment: again, what is this thing in the center? It is not clear from the photo. Is it something that looks like an electric connector? Or some kind of lock?

Comment: What is 'thermonalogy'?

Comment: I just edited the post with a close up picture, if that is to any help. It does not look like a lock. I meant to write terminology , as in I'm not sure anything I'm saying is correct.

Comment: It looks vaguely like a TV antenna socket. What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Are you able to remove the frame? A flat screwdriver should do (if it is anything of electric/tv socket)

Comment: I'm in one of the nordic countries. If it is to any help for further deduction: I already have a TV antenna socket in this room (dorm room).

Comment: Try to illuminate the inside of the opening so we can see what's in there

Comment: I managed to finesse the frame off with a flat screwdriver as adviced. I have edited the post with a new picture.

Comment: @JYelton "terminology"

Comment: @Average_guy It's a flex outlet plate. Is there any evidence nearby that an extractor fan could have been fitted?

Comment: Huh, any chance of turning it into a normal power outlet? My stove is located slightly to the left (under the kitchen cupboard), so it is plausible that it was used for an extractor fan.

Comment: IMO THAT IS CLEARLY AN AC OUTLET.  "N" and "L" are likely "NEUTRAL" and "LINE", but "L" is also marked "M2", meaning "M1" could be an opposite phase. To be absolutely blunt and no offense intended (really)...  All you needed to do is stick a voltmeter on those pins to determine if there is voltage there, but you didn't. You took pictures and posted on the internet.  That means you don't know what you are doing.  I strongly suggest you put the cover back on and call an electrician.

Comment: Never have I pretended to be anything else than an unknowing stranger on the internet, so no offense taken. In my unknowing head, I hoped there would be some sort of 'plug and play' to convert it into my desired socket. I now know that it requires expertise, so I'm going to consult an electrician. Thank you everybody.

Comment: If you are in Europe, most likely you are not legally allowed to do any modifications, because (a) it's a dorm room so clearly not yours to modify even if you call an electrician, and (b) depending on country you are not legally allowed to modify building wiring anyway because you are not a certified electrician with enough knowledge to work on mains.

Comment: I've seen these used to power old style mains clocks. They typically were wired with thin cable and fused back at the switchboard with a 1amp fuse.